# Odoo point of sale invoice button auto click

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

In point of sale module after we click <kbd>Payment</kbd> button there is a button named <kbd>Invoice</kbd>.

[image: Invoice Button IMG]

We can click that button for some function inside that button.

My question is how to **auto click that button** when the form open (`onLoad`)?

In jQuery I can do this:

```
$(document).load({
    $('#btnId').click();
});
```

How to implement that concept click button in Odoo so the <kbd>Invoice</kbd> button is automatically clicked when form payment opens?

I'm using Odoo 10, you can correct me if my question is wrong.

Comment: You can do this in the code of "Payment Button" click. In this you can do like at the time of payment screen is there on cliking of pay button you can by default selected invoice button